# How do you schedule an email in C# using Gmail?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, gmail

So, this is my email function, that sends an email using Gmail's SMTP:

```
public void Email(string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                message.From = new MailAddress(email, emailname);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(targetemail, targetname));
                message.Subject = subject;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(folder + @"\" + cbPrezentacja.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + extension));
                message.Body = body;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

It works however, how would I schedule the email for a specific time? I don't mean making a Windows schedule/timer on the host (that requires leaving it on) or whatever, I want to do it via Gmail.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNG9D.png < This is how it works using Gmail. (sorry for the weird tint)

Is this even possible using System.Net.Mail or do I need a special Gmail API for that (if so, how?)? This is a private application for 1 computer, so it doesn't need to be super secure.

Thanks!

Comment: Any code examples?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69698/Set-the-Time-for-E-Mail-Sending-from-your-NET-Appl) could help?

Comment: 高鵬翔 Did you read what I said? This uses a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
There's nothing in SMTP to schedule it, when you do smtp.Send(message); the message is sent that exact moment.
Gmail [has an API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/), but (as far I can see) it doesn't offer this functionality, so right now the only way to do it would be exactly what you say you don't want: your app should somehow wait till the desired time and send it.